# How do you view your object list when using databricks notebooks?

Tags: r, azure-databricks

Potentially a simple question...

So when using RStudio IDE you have the beautiful and very handy Object explorer on the top right. Which quickly lets you know what your objects are called, how many rows etc.. It is especially handy for when you have many to keep track of, and even more so when your code is b0rked and it shows your dataframe has the wrong number of rows that your expecting.

But, in a Databricks notebooks, I cant see anywhere that has a view of your objects like that? Does it not exist? Or am I missing something?

Comment: You can execute commands like `dim(my_df)` or `str(my_list)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no UI in databricks to view objects.

For this feature you can submit an idea [here](https://databricks.com/feedback)

To inspect the names of the elements use names(my_df) or str(my_df), which provides a richer overview over your data object.

Sample code –

```
my_df <- data_frame(dbl_vec,chr_vec,log_vec)
head(my_df)
```

Output -

```
 dbl_vec chr_vec log_vec
    <dbl> <chr>   <lgl>  
1      1. a       TRUE   
2      2. b       TRUE   
3      3. c       FALSE  
4      4. d       TRUE   
5      5. e       FALSE  
6      6. f       FALSE  



dim(my_df)
[1] 20  3
```

Reference - https://therbootcamp.github.io/BaselRBootcamp_2018April/_sessions/D1S2_Objects/Objects_practical_answers.html

Comment: I don't like the answer, but it is the right answer i guess :(  thanks! At least i know i wasnt missing something.

Answer (score 0):

Databricks recently released a variable explorer for Python starting from Databricks Runtime 12.1. More details at https://docs.databricks.com/notebooks/notebooks-code.html#variable-explorer-1

This provides an overview of the variables defined, the shape and schema for data frames, and the ability to do deeper introspection of variables with a one-click action.